# Calculate Reference URI for KeyInfo in Soap Header Python

Tags: python, cryptography, openssl, rsa, sha1

I am trying to generate the Security headers for my Soap XML request , I could calculate Digest value and Signature Value . I need to populate The following Value of URI  in KeyInfo-->SecurityTokenReference-->Reference ,

```
<wsse:Reference ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" URI="#X509-623242F9C597DEB5EB1425871479922117"/>
```

Following is how I am calculating the rest of the values :

```
signed_info = canonicalize(signed_info, c14n_exc)
#Sign the SHA1 digest of the signed xml using RSA cipher
pkey = RSA.load_key(private_key, lambda *args, **kwargs: password)
signature = pkey.sign(hashlib.sha1(signed_info).digest())
```

Comment: That's nice. And your question is?

Comment: apologies...seems like I wrote an incomplete question ... I will be deleting this post ... I have posted another question since I have moved ahead from this problem . Will appreciate if you can answer there .

[meta]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28996701/code-calculating-wrong-digest-value-using-python[meta]